# JavaScript library more efficient than Rickshaw for realtime visualizations

Tags: optimization, d3.js, real-time, visualization, rickshaw

I want to visualize data as time-series graphs on mobile devices(tablets) and therefore stumbled upon rickshaw, which is based on D3. First I must say I was a little bit confused when I realized that realtime in web design is defined totally different to realtime in engineering which has fixed(and often very short) timeframes. Anyway my aim is to visualize the data as fast as possible, and on older tablets visualization with rickshaw is quite slow.
Can anybody recommend another library, which may be more efficient in rendering?

Or is there no way out and I have to go native?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the library but the implementation?

Comment: actually my code is quite simple i receive data via websockets, put it into an array, and when new data is received i shift the values. Each time i receive the data the rickshaw graph is rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to differ two types of visualizing frameworks: There are frameworks based on SVG and HTML 5 Canvas. SVG is a nicer solution to provide interaction in your visualization, because the SVG elements can be addressed within the DOM. The tradeoff is that real-time visualizations are slow for SVG. On the other side HTML 5 Canvas is bad for interaction, but faster in real-time rendering. Long story short: Rickshaw is based on SVG and maybe you have better performance with a HTML Canvas based framework like:

- [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/)
- [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/)
- [Cubism](https://square.github.io/cubism/)

You could try them with sample visualizations and compare their benchmark results.

Here you have some benchmark examples:

- [Benchmarking Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/tests/dygraph-many-points-benchmark.html)
- [Comparison between D3.js (Canvas), Sigma.js (Canvas), Processing.js (Canvas) and D3.js (SVG)](http://nad.webfactional.com/ntap/graphscale/)
- [Blog post for Comparison between SVG and Canvas](http://www.nickdiakopoulos.com/2012/05/14/visualization-performance-in-the-browser/)

Comment: Why Canvas is bad for interaction?

Comment: So if I got you right if I don't want to interact with the data, canvas might be better(I wonder if displaying the current value like here: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html the hover details counts as interacting) So there hasn't been any benchmarking for those libraries for real realtime applications(not the web realtime cubism: ..."hundreds of metrics updating every ten seconds"). For example visualizing 100 points within 5ms. Thx

Comment: @dan kutz: Yes hovering counts as interaction. The svg can be addressed in the DOM to get the mouse over event. There are a few benchmarking tests. I will update them in my response.

Comment: @MarcoCI: Canvas is ok for interaction, but not via the DOM. You have to save the position of each drawn element separately to enable events on the element.

Comment: So the question can not be answered in a simple way, it depends if you want to interact with the data. As rickshaw doesn't use the Canvas (at least I think so) it will be slower in pure visualizing than other libs. Additionally I guess visualizing within a native app would be even faster. Or is that wrong?

Comment: I agree with you. Visualizations in native app should be faster and the decision between SVG and HTML 5 Canvas depends on performance and interaction needs.

Answer (score 1):

Best library I've found for streaming data is [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org). Performance is very good, but you don't get a lot of options for styling.

Comment: 7 years later this lib is still such a great choice if you want to get nice smooth real-time plots up and running quickly